# Texture makes entire scene Black and White? OpenTK

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I have a texture where it is a 4x4 grid in a 256x256 pixel jpg. If i use that picture for my texture, my entire scene turns black and white. However if I use a different pattern, a checkerboard, the scene has color again. I did make the 2nd texture in GIMP if that has something to do with it. I have quite a lot of code so If anyone has an idea what could be the problem that would be awesome. Otherwise, I will paste bin the code so that you can probably find the one thing I missed lol.

Basically, I just followed the StencilCSG OpenTK example for loading a jpg. I also used the wrap modes for textures. It seems like if I just use some random texture from Google Images it works but my own textures make it all black and white. I think it has to do with how GIMP saves the files in SRGB but idk.

EDIT:

I found a work around right after I decided to post a question. I just disable textures after I render my textured square. I found a FAQ for opengl textures that said to disable and enable when needed. This works but I didnt think you needed to do that. Anyway, I would still love to know what was happening behind the scenes to make my scene black and white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution, turn off textures after you render all of your textured polys.